# Що означає слово "паперівка"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У пісні Мельниковича [Мацьонька](https://www.cheremhi.com.ua/text/slova.php?id=3570) натрапила на такі слова:

> Іде дівчина і світить очима
>
> Солодка дівка, як **паперівка**.

Цікаво, що означає слово паперівка? У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/paperivka) такого слова немає.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Словнику українських говірок Карпатського регіону: «П», «Р», «С». Дмитро Савчук](https://evrika.if.ua/88/) знаходимо:

> **Папірка, паперівка** – ранній сорт яблук; сорт волоських горіхів, який має нетверду оболонку і виповнене зерно.

На сайті  [Ямельницька говірка та ямельницький словник](https://jamelnycia.io.ua/s204582/yamelnicka_govirka_ta_yamelnickiy_slovnik):

> **Паперівка** – сорт яблук.

Отже, дівка солодка, як доспіле яблуко.